# Prevent deletion of child record if other child record exists in another table

Tags: database, postgresql, validation

How do I prevent deleting a record in table Child A, if a record in table Child B is present.

Child A and Child B are referencing the same parent record.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9Swf.png)

Comment: Which implies that single children are not allowed? Please rephrase ...

Comment: Well, there is a slight chance that one child existed before the second one? Then: how did the record get there anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you don't want to delete any records in child_a if there is a child_b record associated with the same parent in the parent table.

if so, this should work (although not efficient if there are a lot of records in child_b):

`delete from child_a where id = 1234 and parent_id not in (select parent_id from child_b)`

Answer (score 0):

Is it prohibited to have a record in table Child B if the corresponding record in table Child A is not present.  (This isn't quite the same as what you said above, although it implies the statement above.)  If this is the case, you have a foreign key relationship between Child A and Child B.  Set the foreign key as a constraint and apply indices as required.

Comment: It is not prohibited to have a record in 'Child B'. If There is a record present in 'Child A' and there is a record present in 'child B' the record in 'child A' can not be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I Have solved this by creating a trigger on table child A.

CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION check_ChildB() RETURNS trigger AS $check_ChildB$
    DECLARE childB_Exists BIGINT;
    BEGIN

```
SELECT ChildB.id FROM ChildB
WHERE OLD.parent_id = ChildB.parent_id INTO childB_Exists;

    IF childB_Exists IS NOT NULL  THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR!!!';
    END IF;
RETURN OLD;
END;
$check_ChildB$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

CREATE TRIGGER delete_ChildA BEFORE DELETE ON ChildA
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_ChildB();